# Java Runtime process was unable to exit after running a set of commands and wait for its output

Tags: java, runtime

Unable to exit from this method once we run commands from it. It stucked in bellow code of StreamHandler class.

```
 while (bufferedReader.read(cb) > 0) {
        cb.flip();
        char[] chars = new char[cb.limit()];
        cb.get(chars);
        System.out.println(new String(chars));
        cb.clear();
 }
```

Any workaround to get rid of this? I use this method to run set of windows cmd commands and wait until they are executed. I don't want to see the output of the executed commands. But I have a requirement to wait until all the commands are executed and exit from this method to execute something else.

```
public synchronized execute_cmd_command(List<String> commandLst) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            Process[] process = {null};

            process[0] = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe");
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(process[0].getOutputStream()));

            commandLst.stream().forEach(s -> {
                try {
                    bufferedWriter.write(s);
                    bufferedWriter.newLine();
                    bufferedWriter.flush();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            });

            StreamHandler streamHandler = new StreamHandler(process[0].getInputStream());
            streamHandler.start();
            streamHandler.join();

        }
```

**Stream Handler Class**

```
public class StreamHandler implements Runnable {

    private InputStream inputStream;
    Thread thread;


    public StreamHandler(InputStream inputStream) {
        this.inputStream = inputStream;
    }

    public void start() {
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    public void join() throws InterruptedException {
        thread.join();
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {

            CharBuffer cb = CharBuffer.allocate(256);
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

            cb.clear();
            while (bufferedReader.read(cb) > 0) {
                cb.flip();
                char[] chars = new char[cb.limit()];
                cb.get(chars);
                System.out.println(new String(chars));
                cb.clear();
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }

}
```

**Process's output is hung up in "`bufferedReader.read(cb) > 0`" line in "`StreamHandler`" class and not returning anything there after.**
Could you guys please provide a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should close process[0].getOutputStream()(also, good to close bufferedWriter) before you start StreamHandler thread:

```
bufferedWriter.close();
process[0].getOutputStream().close();
```

**bufferedReader.read(cb)** will block until some input is available, an I/O error occurs, or the end of the stream is reached.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#read(char[])

Since, process[0].getOutputStream() is piped to the input stream of the process, you should close OutputStream otherwise bufferedReader.read(cb) will be blocked.